# What exploits involve making long http requests with lots of mostly null byte octals?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, web-server, exploit

I've gotten a lot of strange http requests in my access logs before, like calls to nonexistent WordPress login scripts and application specific locations. I've even gotten a few wise guy requests like `...GET /your-site-sucks HTTP/1.1 400...`.

I'm curious about some that have varying lengths of octal characters. Here's an example:

```
x.x.x.x - - [31/Aug/2019:15:20:13 -0400] "\x01A\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" 400 157 "-" "-"
```

I understand this as `Start of heading start of text null null null null null....`.
Looking up the ip address, I found it was labeled as an abusive ip.

**What kind of exploit is this particular request looking for?**

Comment: 157 means that the response body was 157 bytes. The time taken to respond is not recorded in the log by default.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: So any idea what exploit they could have been looking for?